# TKinter multipage GUI Updating Labels from background task

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

I have a multipage GUI and created a background function "def data_scan" which collects new data (which are distance sensors on a robot) and updates some global variables.  I am not sure the best way to handle updating the labels in the Pages.  I am trying within data_scan to set the label txt within the pages.  However the error is cannot find page1.label etc etc.

QUESTION:  I am not sure if the Page(x) should call the variable data routinely or if the data_scan function should set the label txt.

here is a sample of the display
[Plot GUI](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v319/rjconway/TechTank/2015-03-08-004824_480x320_scrot.png)
[Main GUI](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v319/rjconway/TechTank/2015-03-08-004317_480x320_scrot.png)

Current code

```
import Tkinter as tk

import time
import thread

L_RAW = 0.1

def data_scan ():
   global Page1
   while 1:
      L_RAW = 23.2  #just a static value at this point
      Page1.label5['text'] = L_RAW


class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class Page1(Page):  #Status Screen
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.root = root

        self.label5 = tk.Label(self, text = "XX cm")
        self.label5.place(x=265, y=255)



class MainApplication(tk.Frame): # Function to Build the Screen Classes
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root
        p1 = Page1(self)

        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self,background='#444444')
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container = tk.Frame(self,background="#888888",)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


        b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text=" Status ", command=lambda:p1.lift())
        b1.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=4)

        thread.start_new_thread(data_scan,())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainApplication(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("480x320")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. Please summarise your problem in a few lines of code, so that it's fast for us to help you.

Comment: Cut down code snippet sorry.  Issue is the data_scan thread I start does not update the label5 in page1